# ng-grid and back button: remembering grid selections and data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a view with an ng-grid, like this:

```
 <div class="ng-grid-style" ng-grid="customersGrid"></div>
```

In the controller of this view I keep a list of customers and a list of selected customers:

```
$scope.customers = [];
$scope.selectedCustomers = [];
```

I also do the binding of the grid with these two:

```
$scope.customersGrid = { 
    data: 'customers',
    selectedCustomers: $scope.selectedCustomers
};
```

I also fetch customers from a URL at the start of the controller instance:

```
$scope.fetchCustomers() = {

    // with $http I bring customers...
    // (...)

    $scope.customers = response.customers
};

$scope.fetchCustomers();
```

In the view I have links to other routes of the same app. These routes associate other views controlled by other controllers.

My problem is that if I navigate from the view containing the ng-grid to another view, and then I use the back button, I lose the state of `$scope.customers` and `$scope.selectedCustomers`.

**This app is an SPA**, so I should be able to keep these two in memory (or elsewhere) along the life of the app instead of having them in the `$scope`

What is the most recommended way of storing these two? I've read that I could use localStorage, sessionStarge, a service, etc. Also I'm not sure how the binding works when NOT USING the scope instead. Can I pass to the grid's data something that is not in the scope? eg:

```
$scope.customersGrid = { 
    data: localStorage.customers,                            // possible?
    selectedCustomers: localStorage.selectedCustomers        // possible?
};
```

Comment: LocalStorage: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is realy easy to use, if you're having a iOS app e.g. you could use the HTML-5-Storage and store the data into the filesystem e.g. "*.json" file, and read that data.
Also you could store cookies $.cookie:[link](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)
But the easiest way, if you wannt to keep it would be the localStorage, but that depends on your app-wishes

Comment: Update: Theres also a plugin for localStorage: [link](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)